# How to format all numbers into millions in Ruby using NumberHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rounding, number-formatting

Ruby newbie here - I'm trying to any number (including thousands) into millions, and then rounded up to 2 decimal places, eg:

```
1499962946.140625 => 1499.97
31135762.5 => 31.14
8952392.3125 => 8.95
77896 => 0.08
5342 => 0.01
```

I've tried to do this using the following but so far it is only rounding the millions correctly, and the thousands stay as thousands. I would also like to drop 'Million' and 'Thousand' from the resultant string:

```
number_to_human(1234567.12345, precision: 2, significant: false)
=> "1.2 Million"
number_to_human(1234.12345, precision: 2, significant: false)
=> "1.23 Thousand"
```

Additionally, is there a way to keep the zeros, e.g. `1276.40` instead of `1276.4` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just doing:

```rb
> (31135762.5 / 1000000).round(2)
# => 31.14
```

If you want to keep the zeros, you can do that:

```rb
> sprintf('%0.02f', 1276.4)
# => "1276.40"
```

But now you have a string.

If you want you also can put this is a function:

```
def format_number(num)
  sprintf('%0.02f', num / 1000000)
end

format_number(31135762.5)
# => "31.14"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - a much clearer solution !

Comment: The `1_000_000` should be a `Float` or `BigDecimal` instead e.g. `1_000_000.0` or `BigDecimal(1_000_000)` because `77896/1_000_000 #=> 0` due to integer division.

Comment: I think it should be noted that using the ```sprintf``` approach ```1.035 #=> 1.04``` and ```1.045 #=> 1.04```.  Odd rounds up at 5 and even rounds down at 5.

Comment: If the default ```sprintf``` rounding behavior is undesirable, I suggest modifying the code from ```sprintf('%0.02f', num)``` to ```sprintf('%0.02f', num.round(2))```.

Comment: Further to @engineersmnky's comment another option is to use [Numeric#fdiv](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv).

Comment: @CarySwoveland ruby the provider of umpteen ways.

Answer (score 2):

```
def doit(n)
  (0.000001 * n).ceil(2)
end
```

```
doit(1499962946.140625) #=> 1499.97
doit(31135762.5)        #=>   31.14
doit(8952392.3125)      #=>    8.96
doit(77896)             #=>    0.08
doit(5342)              #=>    0.01
```

See [Float#ceil](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Float.html#method-i-ceil).

For the third example, the question shows the desired result to be `8.95`, which is obtained by simple rounding, yet the question states that values should be "...rounded *up* to 2 decimal places".

Comment: "...rounded up to 2 decimal places".  Nice catch.  I completely missed that.